# Add security/authentication to mongodb (2.6) without downtime?

Tags: authentication, replication, high-availability, mongodb

We have a 3 node replica set (running 2.6.1) that's running mostly defaults. We'd like to add authentication, but do it without downtime. I'm fine with restarting the nodes one-by-one and even resyncing the data if need be.

Is this possible? If so, what are the (generic) steps? I was hoping for something like:

1. Add users
2. Add auth=true to each config
3. Restart each node one-by-one

The above doesnt work due to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15048 (as soon as I add users to the primary, I have secondaries crash). So is this possible? I've seen older posts about MongoDB 2.0 not allowing this, but wasnt sure if this now available or not.

Comment: Have you tried your solution? If you start with the secondaries and shut down the primary instead of having it step down, an election would take place with like 2 seconds of downtime. Then, when you start the old primary with auth, it should be working. Make sure to use a keyfile, though. And please try in a test environment first.

Comment: It appears the bug I listed wasnt actually tied to this (since it says its not fixed as of 2.6.5) - I upgraded to 2.6.5 and things worked as expected.